# Typo mistake while accessing put request through Rest APi

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing **REST API** through angularjs and I am accessing `put`-method to modify the content. When I do the modification on the data and click on `save()` button  **json-data** will get deleted and throws undefined function in the console
HTML :

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="toggle_edit()"> Edit </button>
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="toggle_save(cts.selectedcontact)"> Save </button>          
</div>

<b> Street:</b> 
   <p ng-hide="editMode"> 
       {{cts.selectedcontact.location.street}} 
  </p>
<input type="text" ng-show="editMode" ng-model="cts.selectedcontact.location.street"><br/>
```

Angular.js:

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(contacts){
  $scope.selectedcontact = [];
         $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + contacts.id)
           data: ({
                   selectedcontact: contacts.selectedcontact
                 })
                .then(function (data){
                  console.log(data)
                    $scope.cts.selectedcontact = data;
                        $scope.toggle_edit();
                  })
                    .error(function (data) {
                        console.log("Error:" + data)
                    });
                };
```

Comment: `$http.put(...) data: ({` That looks like a typo. You probably want to replace`)` with a comma.

Comment: put(url, data, [config]); What you wrote doesn't look anything like that?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Funnily it is valid javascript, `data:` is simply treated as a label. Though that's probably not what most people would expect it to mean.

Comment: @slebetman: I know, but still a typo...

Comment: The `.error` method is deprecated and removed from AngularJS v1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some typo mistakes are there

```
$scope.toggle_save = function(contacts){
      $scope.selectedcontact = [];
      $http.put('http://localhost:3000/contacts/' + contacts.id, {
           selectedcontact: contacts.selectedcontact
       }).then(function (data){
          // success callback
          console.log(data)
          $scope.cts.selectedcontact = data;
          $scope.toggle_edit();
       }, function (data) {
           // error callback
           console.log("Error:" + data)
       });
};
```

Comment: @kishore DId u removed ) after contacts.id ??

Comment: @kishore thats not a very helpful comment. What do you mean it "doesnt work"? Do you get an error? Do you get a different result to what you expect?

Comment: @kishore I think you've not checked your code matches what is in this answer. If it did you wouldnt get that error any more. I think you have an extra or missing `)` or `}`

Comment: Actually Put is working. But wen i click on the `edit button` and save the changes. Except the id, Complete json-body is getting erased

Comment: @kishore probable cause for your problem could be `$scope.cts.selectedcontact = data;` this line. Just check by debugging your code.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare This the Error what i got in my concole : $http.put(...).then(...).error is not a function

Comment: @kishore which angular js version you are using ?? According to 1.5.0 `error` function is removed. I updated my answer by `success callback` and `error callback` function calls into `then` function.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare I am using Angular 1.6.5

Comment: @KaustubhKhare Actually callback is working fine. But the thing is, entire json-object is gettting deleted. Finally id number will be left out

Comment: @kishore what is your put response `data` ??

Comment: @KaustubhKhare I have updated  few data in plnkr . U can view it here https://plnkr.co/edit/XB1JlIeKrNf1LxxJEumt?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154881/discussion-between-kishore-and-kaustubh-khare).